# I want filter by previous near date my dataframe to a given date

Tags: r, date, filter

I have this dataframe

```
   Data <- c("2013-08-03", "2013-09-04", "2013-09-08", "2013-09-12", "2013-11-01")
   prezzi <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
   t <- data.frame(Data, prezzi)

   Time <- "2013-09-11"
```

I want filter the dataframe `Data` by previous near date to a given date `Time`

The output is

```
Data         Prezzi
2013-09-08     3
```

I use this code `filter(Data == t$Data[which.min(abs(Time - as.Date(t$Data)))])`
and it doesn't work. The result is 2013-09-12 but I want previous near date (2013-09-08.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subtract 1 from the `which.min`.  If the 'Data' is not arranged, we may need to the order it first

```
t1 <- t[order(t$as.Date(Data)),]
i1 <- with(t1, which.min(abs(as.Date(Time) - as.Date(Data)))-1)
t1[i1, , drop = FALSE]
#        Data prezzi
#3 2013-09-08      3
```

---

If we are using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
t %>%
    mutate(Data = as.Date(Data)) %>%
    arrange(Data) %>%
    slice(which.min(abs(as.Date(Time) - Data)) - 1)
#        Data prezzi
#1 2013-09-08      3
```

#### Update

If the OP is not considering based on previous row, but just the rows that is from a minimal difference from 'Time', then use `findInterval`

```
Time <- "2013-09-09"
t[findInterval(as.Date(Time), as.Date(t$Data)),]
#        Data prezzi
#3 2013-09-08      3
```

Comment: But it doesn't work if i put `Time <- "2013-09-09"`. The result is `2013-09-04` and i want `2013-09-08`

Comment: @Andrea Can you check my update with `findInterval`

Comment: @Andrea with that date, I get the 2nd row

Comment: @Andrea What if your first row was `2013-09-02`

Comment: yes it work with findinterva. If I want filter my dataframe for two conditions. For example `Time <- "2013-09-09" and Time-months(1)`. How can i change code?

Comment: In that case with `dplyr` it would be `t %>% filter(between(as.Date(Data), time1, Time))`

Answer (score 1):

Less straightforward than @akrun's answer, you can filter first for date below "Time" and then keep the maximum date in the subset:

```r
library(dplyr)
t %>% filter(as.Date(Data) < as.Date(Time)) %>%
  filter(as.Date(Data) == max(as.Date(Data)))

        Data prezzi
1 2013-09-08      3
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Using base R only this gives the largest date prior to Time:

```
tail(subset(t, Time > format(Data)), 1)
##         Data prezzi
## 3 2013-09-08      3
```

**2)** or using dplyr:

```
t %>%
  filter(Time > format(Data)) %>%
  slice(n())
```

**3)** or using sqldf:

```
library(sqldf)

fn$sqldf("select max(Data) Data, prezzi from t
  where '$Time' > Data")
##         Data prezzi
## 1 2013-09-08      3
```

Answer (score 0):

One way in base R would be :

```
#Convert to date class
t$Data <- as.Date(t$Data)
Time <- as.Date("2013-09-11")

#Get difference between date and time
inds <- t$Data - Time
#Select the one with minimum difference
t[inds == max(inds[inds < 0 ]), ]

#        Data prezzi
#3 2013-09-08      3
```